# Why check for !document.xmlVersion in bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, dom, bookmarklet

I see a [very common](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=b%26%26!document.xmlVersion) boilerplate pattern for bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:var%20b=document.body;if(b&&!document.xmlVersion){void(/*do_something_AWESOME_here*/);}else{}
```

What is the reasoning behind including the !document.xmlVersion check?  Is it simply a matter of excluding older browsers? Verifying that we are in an HTML document, and not an XML doc?  The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.xmlVersion) does not exactly clarify matters... I have not been able to find any explanatory statements on this - it mostly looks like a case of copyandpasteitus.

Updated 5/21/2012 to include link to Google search for pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the document suggests it was required for the older versions to check if the document was being rendered as xml rather than html. now its of no use in the latest versions of the browsers. IT is not used in the recent versions of the browsers.

Comment: Yes - as the documentation states - so why is 'everyone' using the check?

Comment: coz in the world every one have nt yet switched to the newer versions of browsers buddy, in my neighbourhood the gov houses still use the older IE.

Comment: @OskarAustegard Strange. I have seen many more bookmarklets that most people - I'm a bit of a collector - and I have never seen this. I'd like to see some examples in the wild where this is being used.

Comment: @DG - see the link in my post - it is used by Boxee, Google Reader, etc: http://goo.gl/Uk9Of

Comment: I'm going to mark this down as a case of copyandpasteitus and call it a day.  Despite simply restating the linked to documentation, Neji claims the price.